# Read, convert .xlsx files to csv and the concatenates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I wrote a code which successfully reads all the .xls files in a directory one by one and then converts it into csv format and finally concatenates them so the program afterwards run on that single concatenated csv file.

This code works with .txt also, simply by replacing .xls with .txt. I thought it will be similar in case of .xlsx format but I was wrong. For some reason it is showing an error.

The code is:

```
path="C:\\Users\\AD\\Downloads\\Excess data"  #Change this directory to the location of your directory.
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "\\*.xls")  #Searches for all files with .txt/.xls.

list_ = []
for file in allFiles:
    print(file)
    bytes = open(file, 'rb').read()
    df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(bytes.decode('utf-8')), sep='\t', parse_dates=['Time'] )
    list_.append(df)

Source = pd.concat(list_)
Source.head()
```

This code runs successfully for .xls and .txt but in case of .xlsx I am getting some error:

```
*UTF-8 can't decode ...at position.. something like this*
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) with list comprehension:

```
#Change this directory to the location of your directory. 
path="C:\\Users\\AD\\Downloads\\Excess data" 

#Searches for all files with .txt/.xls.
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "\\*.xls")  

list_ = [pd.read_excel(file) for file in allFiles]
Source = pd.concat(list_, ignore_index=True)
print Source

#convert to csv
Source.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Same error.

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 10: invalid start byte

Comment: I have 2 ideas - use `list_ = [pd.read_excel(file, encoding='utf-8')['Time'] for file in allFiles]`

Comment: Or: `[pd.read_csv(file, encoding='utf-8',  sep='\t', parse_dates=['Time'] ) for file in allFiles]`

Comment: Just to confirm, where do I have to put this list_=? In place of list_.append(df) or in the beginning where list=[] is written?

Comment: @user68263 - under `allFiles = glob.glob(path + "\\*.xls")`, need only my code, no loop necessary

Comment: Done. Works! Thank you. Also, how to further convert it into csv?

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot.